# Is there a way to get the latest Reputation from Data Explorer

Tags: support, reputation, badges, data-explorer, api

Why is my reputation and badge count in data explorer different from the actual ones in Stack Exchange? Is there a way to get the exact updated reputation by using a query there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Data Explorer runs on a copy of the SE database, this copy is updated every week or so. To get the current reputation you would have to run the queries on the production database.

Allowing random users to query the production database would obviously be a terrible idea.

Comment: I needed access to prod database to build an android widget show rep and badges for the registered user, by nevermind :) thanks just the same.

Comment: @mlaferla you can use the API if you need current information

Comment: can you send me a link to that please?

Comment: @mlaferla https://api.stackexchange.com/docs

Comment: Do note that SEDE is not an exact copy so you miss certain information to get spot-on rep. I have something that comes close [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144716/reputation-history-from-data-explorer/234414#234414).